# Drawing all possible Polylines between multiple google maps markers?

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have an Arraylist containing latitudes and longitudes (retrieved from sqlite database) which I am using to set markers on the map, I'm currently trying to draw all possible Polylines between those markers using this code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.size() - 1; i++) {
            LatLng src = list.get(i);
            LatLng dest = list.get(i + 1);

            // mMap is the Map Object
            Polyline line = CalRout.mMap.addPolyline(
                    new PolylineOptions().add(
                            new LatLng(src.latitude, src.longitude),
                            new LatLng(dest.latitude,dest.longitude)
                    ).width(3).color(color)
            );
        }
```

..but as you can see in the screenshot below I am not getting all possible Polylines.

[Screenshot of result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ef9t7.png)

I am thinking nested loop, but I am not sure how do I go about implementing it, help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Random random = new Random();
for (LatLng positionI : list) {
    for (LatLng positionJ : list) {
        int color = Color.rgb(random.nextInt(255), random.nextInt(255), random.nextInt(255));
        if (positionI != positionJ) {
            Polyline line = CalRout.mMap.addPolyline(
                    new PolylineOptions().add(
                            positionI,
                            positionJ
                    ).width(3).color(color)
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, working like a charm !
While we are at it is there a way to give a different color for each iteration of the inner loop?

Comment: Yes, just assign a different value for the color on each iteration

Comment: I could only think of this:

`Random rnd = new Random();
int color = Color.argb(255, rnd.nextInt(256), rnd.nextInt(256),
rnd.nextInt(256));`

but it's not working, I get the same color for all iterations.

Answer (score 0):

Your idea is correct. To implement nested loop, simply insert another loop inside original.

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.size() - 1; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < list.size() - 1; j++) {
        if (j != i) { // skip same point
            LatLng src = list.get(i);
            LatLng dest = list.get(j);

            // mMap is the Map Object
            Polyline line = CalRout.mMap.addPolyline(
                new PolylineOptions().add(
                    new LatLng(src.latitude, src.longitude),
                    new LatLng(dest.latitude,dest.longitude)
                    ).width(3).color(color)
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am still getting the same result as earlier.